# Python 3.13, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

Tags: python-3.x

Environment: Kubuntu 22.04  |  6.5.0-17 Kernel
Python: Old 3.10 -> New 3.13

Wanted to try the new python version, so i added the repo in my installation and sudo apt installed python3.13 (Installed: python3.13 python3.13-dev python3.13-minimal)

Then i tried to install all my old packages(the ones that have a 3.13 version) with this python script (using my old python)

```
pkgs = eval(str(sbp.run("pip3 list -o --format=json", shell=True,
                         stdout=sbp.PIPE).stdout, encoding='utf-8'))
for pkg in pkgs:
    sbp.run("python3.13 -m pip install " + pkg['name'], shell=True)
```

and im greeted with errors. I then tried to do it from the terminal manually to try and see whats wrong.
Type python3.13 -m pip install SomePackage, i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import getLogger
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

And its not just for one package, but for all of them.

What can i do to fix this?
Thank you in advance

I tried installing and reinstalling python, nothing changed

tried python3.13 -m pip install setuptools ,just throws the error above

tried python3.13 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools, just throws the error above

tried sudo apt install python3.13-distutils, doesnt exist

tried sudo apt install python3.13-setuptools, doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

I usually encounter less errors when I set up python using [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes) and [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). You might also be able to make this work without deadsnakes.

```bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y software-properties-common  # for add-apt-repository
# add https://github.com/deadsnakes
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
# remove again as it was only needed to run the add-apt-repository python script
apt-get purge -y software-properties-common
# install python3.13 from deadsnakes
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python3.13 python3.13-dev python3.13-venv
# set up a virtual environment and prefer its entrypoints by prepending to PATH
export VIRTUAL_ENV="/usr/share/python3/app"
export PATH="${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin:${PATH}"
python3.13 -m venv ${VIRTUAL_ENV}
# install packages in the virtual environment (this 'pip' now points to ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/pip)
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
```